# Shape of the received image in Flask

Tags: python, flask, request

I want to receive image from POST request and than print out shape of the image. When I run my app I get

> object has no attribute 'shape'

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def take_image():
    input_file = request.files.get('file')
    image = input_file
    return image.shape
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create and Image object from the input file

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(input_file)
width, height = im.size
```

For more information refer to [PIL documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/Image.html)